# How to apply a gradient on a UI Tab Bar In Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, uitabbar

I built the tab bar through the storyboard, and to customise the colour I change it in the app delegate, with `UITabBar.appearance().barTintColor = Color`,

I have a gradient method which is this:

```
func setGradientBackground(colorOne: UIColor, colorTwo: UIColor)  {
    let gradientlayer = CAGradientLayer()
    gradientlayer.frame = bounds
    gradientlayer.colors = [colorOne.cgColor, colorTwo.cgColor]
    gradientlayer.locations = [0, 1]
    gradientlayer.startPoint = CGPoint(x: 1.0, y: 0.0)
    gradientlayer.endPoint = CGPoint(x: 0.0, y: 0.0)

    layer.insertSublayer(gradientlayer, at: 0)

}
```

How do I apply this to the background of my tab bar?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Just create a subclass of `UITabBarController`

```
class GradientTabBarController: UITabBarController {

        let gradientlayer = CAGradientLayer()

        override func viewDidLoad() {
            super.viewDidLoad()
            setGradientBackground(colorOne: .yellow, colorTwo: .red)
        }

        func setGradientBackground(colorOne: UIColor, colorTwo: UIColor)  {
            gradientlayer.frame = tabBar.bounds
            gradientlayer.colors = [colorOne.cgColor, colorTwo.cgColor]
            gradientlayer.locations = [0, 1]
            gradientlayer.startPoint = CGPoint(x: 1.0, y: 0.0)
            gradientlayer.endPoint = CGPoint(x: 0.0, y: 0.0)
            self.tabBar.layer.insertSublayer(gradientlayer, at: 0)
        }
}
```

Assign `GradientTabBarController` class in the storyboard instead of `UITabBarController`

**Main pros of this methodology are below.**

1. No need to define delegate methods of `UITabBar`
2. No need to write code in each `UIViewController`

Comment: How would I apply this to the icons of the tab bar?

Comment: You just need to give a class in storyboard and rest of things worked as it is.

Comment: How do I give it a class when it comes from the tab bar controller?

Answer (score 2):

## Step 1

Assuming that you have built a tab bar that way, make sure it's the delegate to your `ViewController`.

[image: step 1]

## Step 2

In your `ViewController.swift` use the following code:

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController, UITabBarDelegate {

    @IBOutlet weak var tabBar: UITabBar!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
        setGradientBackground(colorOne: .blue, colorTwo: .red)
    }

    func setGradientBackground(colorOne: UIColor, colorTwo: UIColor)  {
        let gradientlayer = CAGradientLayer()
        gradientlayer.frame = tabBar.bounds
        gradientlayer.colors = [colorOne.cgColor, colorTwo.cgColor]
        gradientlayer.locations = [0, 1]
        gradientlayer.startPoint = CGPoint(x: 1.0, y: 0.0)
        gradientlayer.endPoint = CGPoint(x: 0.0, y: 0.0)

        self.tabBar.layer.insertSublayer(gradientlayer, at: 0)

    }
}
```

## Result

[image: result]

Comment: How it can be done for also filling the bottom safe area?

Comment: @BrenoVinícios Not sure if my logic is correct or not, for filling bottom, i increased height of gradient layer frame. works for me.

Answer (score 0):

✅ quick solution, this will **completely fill the background with a gradient**

```
func setTabGradientBackground(frame: CGRect ,colorOne: UIColor, colorTwo: UIColor, insertTo: CALayer )  {
    let gradientlayer = CAGradientLayer()
    gradientlayer.name = "GradientLayerKey"
    gradientlayer.frame = frame
    gradientlayer.colors = [colorOne.cgColor, colorTwo.cgColor]
    gradientlayer.locations = [0, 1]
    gradientlayer.startPoint = CGPoint(x: 0.0, y: 0.0)
    gradientlayer.endPoint = CGPoint(x: 1.0, y: 1.0)
    insertTo.insertSublayer(gradientlayer, at: 0)
}
```

Usage

```
override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
    super.viewDidLayoutSubviews()
    setTabGradientBackground(
        frame: tabBar.bounds,
        colorOne: .blue,
        colorTwo: .red,
        insertTo: tabBar.layer
    )
}
```