# How to apply gradient over tab bar icon in Swift 4?

Tags: swift, user-interface, uitabbarcontroller, uitabbar

I'm trying to add a gradient to my icons in my tab bar, currently, I found a solution on here in a way to make the tab bar gradient, I think this is close, but how do I use it for tab icons? Similar to this https://i.stack.imgur.com/0xwQu.jpg

```
class GradientTabBarController: UITabBarController {

    let gradientlayer = CAGradientLayer()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        setGradientBackground(colorOne: .yellow, colorTwo: .red)
    }

    func setGradientBackground(colorOne: UIColor, colorTwo: UIColor)  {
        gradientlayer.frame = tabBar.bounds
        gradientlayer.colors = [colorOne.cgColor, colorTwo.cgColor]
        gradientlayer.locations = [0, 1]
        gradientlayer.startPoint = CGPoint(x: 1.0, y: 0.0)
        gradientlayer.endPoint = CGPoint(x: 0.0, y: 0.0)
        self.tabBar.layer.insertSublayer(gradientlayer, at: 0)
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you talking about [How to apply a gradient on a UI Tab Bar In Swift?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55996666/how-to-apply-a-gradient-on-a-ui-tab-bar-in-swift)

Comment: @rmaddy thats how to apply it to a tab bar background, i want it for the icons, but yes